# Factory Pattern example - need solution to the below code

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
package com.factory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

//Factory class
class FactoryClass {
        Map products = new HashMap();

        void registerProduct(String prodId, ProductInt prodInterface) {
            products.put(prodId, prodInterface);
        }

        ProductInt createProduct(String prodId) {
            return ((ProductInt) products.get(prodId)).createProduct();
        }
}    

// Client
public class FactoryPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FactoryClass factory = new FactoryClass();
        factory.createProduct("pen");
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.factory;

//Interface Product
public interface ProductInt {
    ProductInt createProduct();
}

// Concrete Product-1
class Pen implements ProductInt {
    static {
        FactoryClass factory = new FactoryClass();
        factory.registerProduct("pen", new Pen());
    }

    public ProductInt createProduct() {
        return new Pen();
    }
}

// Concrete Product-2
class Pencil implements ProductInt {
    static {
        FactoryClass factory = new FactoryClass();
        factory.registerProduct("pencil", new Pencil());
    }
    public ProductInt createProduct() {
        return new Pencil();
    }

}
```

When I run this code, I get nullpointer as no products are registered in hashmap. So, when I requested for a Product instance for "pencil", it couldnt find any key to return me the concrete Pencil class object.can any one help me coding this -- like there should not be any relation directly between Factory and concrete class, so that the registration will remain outside of Factory class and I should get the proper concrete class object which I request for?

Thanks
Balaji

Comment: "I get nullpointer": where, caused by what?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating separate instances of your `FactoryClass` - each of these instances have thier own `Map products` instances within them - the factory that you create in your `main()` method is different from the factory that you create and register your `pen` and `pencil` with. Obviously there are no items registered in the `FactoryClass.products`.

One way is to declare the `Map products` in your `FactoryClass` as `static` - that would solve your immediate problem - even though as a whole your code seems to be in need of other improvements at other places.

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues:

First, factory methods should either be `static` or in a different class than the class being created. Therefore having a `interface` whose sole method is creating an instance of the interface is not really logical. You could have a case where `InterfaceA` creates an instance of `InterfaceB` or where the interface is generic `FactoryInterface<X>` and creates an instance of `X`. See Guava's  [Supplier](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html) interface

Take for example, `Pen`... can can't call `Pen.createProduct()` unless you already have an instance of `Pen` since the method is not static.

So given the above, consider having your `Factory` take a `Producer<X>` or `Supplier<X>` to create instances of `X`.

Second, consider making your factory class a `Singleton`. The issue that you are having is that each static initialized creates a new factory instance which is immediately thrown away. Therefore when you try to get the mapped value later you are getting it from a different instance than the one on which it was registered.

Finally, static initializers of classes are not invoked until the class is utilized / touched in some way. You need to invoke something on `Pen` and `Pencil` to get their static initializer blocks to be invoked and thereby registering themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above the http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html says:
We have to make sure that the concrete product classes are loaded before they are required by the factory for registration(if they are not loaded they will not be registered in the factory and createProduct will return null). To ensure it we are going to use the Class.forName method right in the static section of the main class.

```
class Main {

static
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("OneProduct");
        Class.forName("AnotherProduct");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException any)
    {
        any.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws PhoneCallNotRegisteredException
{
    ...
}
}
```